ZPL label prints from ZebraDesigner but not sending it using TextOnly printer
I used ZebraDesigner to design a label with some logos. The label prints correctly directly from ZebraDesigner to the printer (GC420d).
Then, I printed the label to a file to get the ZPL code. This is the ZPL code:
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTD^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR4,4~SD30^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW472
^LL0320
^LS0
^FO0,192^GFA,00768,00768,00012,:Z64:eJy9kb0RgzAMRuVQUHoEj2JGSJN57HFymYJRKFNScjkSxfoDnBx0iYundzrOyPoA/nvyAgi9AU44FCJ7S6UV99T34oFKEE/UT+L47BTQUNvhHdgN5baXoZSZMLH7yVBuHg0AkaYJw+eUELNh39MC89t1dZyPnCfE42/EL2cu2VD/d3fO3lC/K2ze60dDvR/ZG49Q7dZRCk6iAHxkhcajGUUKJn7nuM23uogT0El/et7WGHqB:438A
^FO256,192^GFA,01024,01024,00016,:Z64:eJzNkjFLw0AUx99rKVdxuOjkIG0QcXBwjig9/AD9Lic4OEgbKbhJVz+Bg44uQpeECBkc/ArRCC6i6XZgyfnSO9JUEaEg+Cfh+PPjvUv+7wH8O21fzeQDoK4oA6hXvQJgVT8B4B+j0ah4C+UA7aKntL3JtIpTWc8B1qucAXR+4YvVI/0IglPWiwT4IMktd6TIgGGY23pPCUU8fbNcSu+YeBRYnihP7RAPDMeAeJ+dRpnh9YC4HurU9me+FOOXWIfa3M99JdLo4ToRhrdBijCMMeBFfY1aqL00fR888SFx5p+A3H2MYoxYUV9PJqC8sR4OTH8cK5BephnG5vtpKnR/j1sO/Ww+v34yn087mM+PslE1cF0X3CnnPki23n1eWdqfcvKqufV6uXF+Uebb3Dy6W+06Zf7Lnduzm/u1kjccbDgHzsLz+3n+rSrn02fGBfkQEQ/RqEe+uq/59/39ut9/q09SY92m:121F
^FO224,192^GFA,00512,00512,00008,:Z64:eJxjYKAOUEDjc6DxmZhfN4AZbDYOYJqrYQeYlg0NANMaQAgBFlADYDTEaA6tDIi0PZSvjWolRxsa3wDCZxGACmRA+SwQ+1mYIMIsjBA+G8MBCJ/BAWrvA6h8AZhOYv4BppnDQ8B0c+MjqMGOYP8BcQNUwIEB4n9UB5EGmP///w8yjx1KE+KTCwDCbyUf:26D6
^FO384,192^GFA,00768,00768,00012,:Z64:eJzN0DEOgjAUBuDXoLZhoJMJkx29goMRj+DiPbiA0jB4Do7SW7hyBEYHwrOEvrYDUdn8E5IvTUr+/gB/klXk7AeryIUOrsx3Y+vJsJt1gq9Zc+y9JQ6R4/Pwf4XnULMJFW5R/RwWh65wA3CkmhrgQOfWVEjaj4qqtX2lc5balznvROl9ShtAPbkSxi93FxqkMzJmeOucJh2bzHDDeyid6/3gCiX4UGhy51rRQByfBQ0nEQsaVOGY2FOf7XXM5fM2i/IGy5pPUg==:F80A
^FO64,192^GFA,00768,00768,00012,:Z64:eJy9kbFtxDAMRamzAaU6j8BNrIyQ5vZIqcKItE+GiEZIkQGEVCmVTggOZngnUtYCCRt/PBPU5yfAv9dDbN/L5QnCe9NEeaK96UAJiZQnx/+Ex/ARyl1XmHZY6l17mK5grsJvcBduE4BTHk+AsXEETFb4ClTP0r8ZamOYv3Q/zO13UF6X7KLwivHcuQPR3pRVd62D3kzZVPNOXnUYNPN68KP/5zV37Yc5/G6f76EgzIcf9ebBY8LDfyX1v1ndkXMY9l0NlVm4i295EY5x5hwlz8zZSp6WjxKkfxry56NYvQvQp2urPd9Wk5t+8RASP48AVu/OdaKexB/WL0uvhEU=:219E
^FO160,192^GFA,00512,00512,00008,:Z64:eJytkCFuw0AQRWfrSstqFLw+RlHtI/QGvUaApbVVYJgrFOcEZV4WmCPUuMjQwPLPn9kkUmClLnn7pZk/f0bkv1+FxdjG1Yi4KRxqY4ERmR/GEmd8kx4nzKYHTGSARyJrfGZu7s5O61sXzWctzVf2Is/KV5EXkd07v2+00xBs8KtGoN50BDWbfUz2LzkwQCMkjusYbSIb1pNblWk+5JIZOE5iIyV1qunB7E2gN7NrTH9CD3oWZ2Un7idrN3IfZnA192tZOOKA1fYc7HA3BtbNV052n974dOx+v/Klm+vFkzzqv7wL28t+jA==:0373
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

Now, I tried to open the label in Notepad++ and print directly to the printer using a TextOnly driver (in Windows) but the printer LED just make some blinks and the label is not printed.
So, I pasted the code in Labelary, and the logos show correctly, so it's seems the code is OK.
I tried creating a label with text and images, using the same method. Using ZebraDesigner the label prints correctly, but saving to a file and printing using Notepad++ only print the text, not the graphics.
I'm a bit lost with this. If the labels prints from ZebraDesigner and show perfect in Labelary, why sending the label ZPL code using a TextOnly printer only prints the text ? Why the printer ignore the graphics ?
I don't see in the graphics code characters that can be reinterpreted or removed from the label. It's just ASCII, like the GFA command expect.
Any idea ???
Thanks!!!

If you create a label without any logos or graphics, does that work?

Yes, I already used this method for text only labels in the past. What is new now are the logos. I tried both text and logos, and only the texts are printed.

Have you tried to remove the first two lines of text? There's "two" labels in that code.

Also, try removing the leading 0s from each of the ^GF arguments.

Sorry, but when you print ZPL code from something like Notepad++, using a normal printer driver, it will simply try to print the ZPL code, as you asked. ZPL is a raw printing format, so you also need to send the ZPL in raw format to the printer.

@KIKOSoftware a text-only driver if sufficent for this!

@Juanjico From ZebraDesigner also print (not save), but redirect the output into a file (in the printer settings)

@Juanjico If that still does not work, try to save the file in ANSI Format, not e.g. UTF-8
